# What does "matchy friends" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Can you explain to me please what does "matchy friends" mean in this sentence? "What you must do at first is to make sure you have chosen the matchy friends to explore a city?"

I checked some dictionaries, but all I could find was "matchy-matchy". Is this usage "matchy friends" correct? I found it in an English coursebook

See http://ogmmateryal.eba.gov.tr/panel/upload/etkilesimli/kitap/ingilizce/11/unite9/index.html#p=11

Comment: It is not a phrase of standard English.  What exactly is the book? What page is it on?

Comment: Found it http://ogmmateryal.eba.gov.tr/panel/upload/etkilesimli/kitap/ingilizce/11/unite9/index.html#p=11

Comment: I think this is an example of a bad English textbook, unfortunately.  "make sure you have chosen the matchy friends" just does not sound like something a native speaker would say.

Comment: Could be a typo for matching friends. Still not great though.

Comment: It's on page 119.  Thank you, this was the book I am talking about. I was preparing a word list of unit 9 for my students

Answer (score 3):

This is an error in the book.  The phrase "matchy friends" isn't, and has never been idiomatic. "Well-matched friends" would be better, or "friends that share your interests" is even better.

The rest of the article is also pretty badly written.  Normally I'd say "get a better book", but that might not be possible if this is the book chosen by your government.  (Perhaps the advice is "get a better government...")

Comment: The cause of the problem is not something related to the government itself here,  maybe about curriculum and linguistic characteristics of Turkish. As you don't know Turkish you may not understand what I mean but teaching English is not the same thing in France and Turkey. There are highly variable factors behind it. And,this is not the only book in which you can find such mistakes in the world.

Comment: As well as bad English, it is also bad advice. You can explore a city alone, or with friends who have different interests.  Finding different friends is not the first thing to do when planning a city break!